# Taking input from user in console in ruby

Tags: ruby, console, user-input

The following program takes two inputs (comma separated) from the user:

```
puts "Enter the code"
input_codes = gets.split(',')
puts "your given code is: "

code_1 = input_codes[0]
code_2 = input_codes[1]

puts code_1=='GEO'
puts code_2=='TYP'
```

Output is the following:

```
Enter the code
> GEO,TYP

true
false
```

It should print `true` for both of the cases, right? Why is it printing `false` for the last case? What am I missing?

EDIT: Yeah, there was an extra newline character that I was missing in the beginning. Fixed the issue with the help of tadman. ANd yeah, the **inspect** thing was pretty cool and useful since then!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have a newline in your input you haven't stripped. When processing data from files, be sure to `chomp` any input values. Even better is to call `strip` which will remove leading and trailing spaces.

```
gets.chomp.split(',')
```

Whenever trying to do diagnostics, it's important to show "invisible" characters:

```
puts code_2.inspect
# "TYP\n"
```

This would probably have exposed the issue sooner. `inspect` can be misleading, though, on custom classes that have their own customized emitter. It can't always be trusted, but it's usually a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

You have a newline at the end of the string, just strip it:

```
input_codes = gets.strip.split(',')
```